# Why does $2x_1x_2y_1y_2 \leq x_1^2y_2^2+x_2^2y_1^2$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

When I tried to prove the triangle inequality $|z_1+z_2| \leq |z_1| + |z_2|$ algebraically for complex variables $z_1$ and $z_2$, I came across this inequality and found that this is always true no matter what.  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: You have: $0\leqslant (x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2$, the rest is trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Develop $(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2\ge0$.